# How to check database with an array parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

Hi, I have an array and I want to pass a variable to a function.

```
'#\@(.*?)\;#si' =>  'some before text' . retrieveName('$1') . 'some after text,'

function retrieveName($poster_id){
    $sanitized_id = sanitizeIn($poster_id);

    $getname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$sanitized_id';") 
                or die(mysql_error());
    $namerow = mysql_fetch_array($getname);
    $exists = mysql_num_rows($getname);

    if($exists == "0"){
      return $sanitized_id;
    } else {
      return $namerow['username'];
    }
}
```

It's supposed to take the value of `$1`, check the database for a user with that id, then return their username. But no parameter is being passed to retrieveName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrieveName function should read:

```
function retrieveName($poster_id){
    $sanitized_id = sanitizeIn($poster_id);
    $get_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$sanitized_id';") or die(mysql_error());
    $name_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_name);
    return $name_row['username'];
}
```

I strongly advise on placing some error checking there though, what happens if the ID is not found?

Edit:

**if** you're trying to do a "preg_replace templating", then the line should read:

```
'#@(.*?);#sie' =>  '"some before text".retrieveName("\1")."some after text"',
```

'e' in the modifiers to execute the code.

This should change, e.g., "Hello, @lserni;, how goes?" with "Hello, some before textLeonardo Sernisome after text, how goes?".

Comment: You're totally right! I edited my original post with a few revisions. The new problem is that it's not finding the user, but when it returns sanitized_id because of 0 rows, that's the right id? I tried echoing it and it gives "$1". Any ideas?

Comment: The code, as is, looks correct. If you have no other means of debugging, try adding "  die("I got poster_id as '$poster_id'!"); " as very first line of retrieveName. That should clue you about what's being actually passed to retrieveName: I'm suspicious of that '$1'. BTW, num_rows is numeric, compare with 0, not with "0" -- it works anyway, but it's a bad habit. I know, for I have it too :-)

Comment: ...also, it makes no sense to fetch array before checking whether the array exists. If num_rows is 0, return immediately. (Do not forget to free your mysql query handle -- makes no difference in small scripts, but in big ones small leaks quickly hog a lot of memory)

Comment: Yep, it threw out "I got poster_id as '$1'!" My only guess is that for whatever reason, $1 is being taken as a literal string and that's why it's sending that to retrieveName. And thanks, I completely skipped over "0".

Comment: I thought $1 was a placeholder. Between single quotes, $ does not work, so '$1' is string literal "dollar one". But I'm editing my answer...

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm, you have been beyond helpful. And I learned a couple things along the way. Cheers